# Char shift to left side using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python.
I want to shift char by its position. for e.g.

pos= 3 then replace c by z , b by y , a by x, Same like C by Z , B by Y and A by X

What I have tried ?
I have tried with hardcoded values as,

```
for i in s:
     if ord(i) == 99:
          return z
     if ord(i) == 98:
          return x
     ...
     ...
```

Is there is any builtin function is available to do this ? or Any other simpler way to achieve this ?

**Edit:**

if string would be `"abcdef"`
the output would be `"xyzabc"`

I user input `"AbCdEf"` then output would be `"XyZaBc"`

Comment: I do not understand the requirement. Can you provide a sample input and the result you'd like to get for it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ord` combined with `chr`:

```
ord("e") + 3
   -> 104
chr(ord("e") + 3)
   -> 'h'
```

Comment: This breaks for the wrap-around cases.

Comment: This is the principle, I guess he can write the algo to treat the extreme cases...

Answer (score 1):

From your requirements, I understand that you need to demonstrate a [Substitution Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). It is very simple to implement. I will give you function outline pseudocode:

```
char substitutionCipher(int leftRotateBy, char alphabet) {
    int pos = (int) alphabet - (int) 'a';
    pos -= leftRotateBy;
    if(pos < 0) {
       pos += 26;
    }
    return (char) (pos + (int) 'a');
}
```

Please note that this outline will work only for lowercase letters. You can modify it to work for uppercase letters also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 2 and you are wanting to convert entire sentences, consider making a character translation table. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans

```
import string

def caesar_shift(secret, shift):
    lcase = string.ascii_lowercase
    ucase = string.ascii_uppercase
    shift = shift % len(lcase) # force shift to be between 0 and 25, inclusive
    trans = string.maketrans(
        ''.join([lcase,ucase]),
        ''.join([lcase[shift:], lcase[shift:],
                  ucase[shift:], ucase[:shift]]))
    return string.translate(secret, trans)
```

Keep in mind that string.maketrans and string.translate were removed in deprecated in Python 3 as part of improving Python's Unicode string handling.

Use negative or positive values to shift left/right.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Answer (score -1):

```
import string

def convert(c, pos):
        charset = string.lowercase
        index = charset.find(c)
        if index >= 0:
                return charset[(index - pos) % len(charset)]

        charset = string.uppercase
        index = charset.find(c)
        if index >= 0:
                return charset[(index - pos) % len(charset)]

        return c

assert convert("c", 3) == "z"
assert convert("b", 3) == "y"
assert convert("a", 3) == "x"
assert convert("C", 3) == "Z"
assert convert("B", 3) == "Y"
assert convert("A", 3) == "X"
```

Update for those who are interested in better performance:

```
import string

def get_converter(pos):
        def rot(s, pos):
                offset = -pos % len(s)
                return s[offset:] + s[:offset]
        def getzip(charset, pos):
                return zip(charset, rot(charset, pos))
        def getdict(pos):
                return dict(getzip(string.ascii_lowercase, pos) + getzip(string.ascii_uppercase, pos))
        chardict = getdict(pos)
        def converter(c):
                return chardict.get(c, c)
        return converter

convert = get_converter(3)

assert convert("c") == "z"
assert convert("b") == "y"
assert convert("a") == "x"
assert convert("C") == "Z"
assert convert("B") == "Y"
assert convert("A") == "X"
assert convert("!") == "!"
```

Comment: Find function has linear running time

Comment: @IceArdor The question doesn't speak about performance optimization, does it? ;-)